# in Tcl, when should use use set vs unset to prepare to use a variable

Tags: tcl

In my scripts, when using a variable, I generally empty the contents of a variable to ensure that the list appends are clean.  Something like the following

```
set var1 [list]
foreach var2 {a b c} {
  lappend var1 $var2
}
```

But it seems like unsetting the variable first would accomplish the same thing.  Something like this

```
unset -nocomplain var1
foreach var2 {a b c} {
  lappend var1 $var2
}
```

Is there any advantage for using one vs the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference in this case. If I was to write such a loop in my own code, I would be more likely to use `set var {}` since that is the empty list literal (as well as being the empty string, the empty dictionary, the empty script, etc.) but there isn't any execution time difference to speak of. It just reflects how I think about scripts.

Of course, if you are doing something where it does matter, use the right one for that case.

Comment: thanks.  But in what situation would it make a difference?

Comment: Can it make a difference in internal representation and shimmering?

Comment: The situations where it would make a difference would be those where you were going to read the variable first, and of course `info exists` would see the difference too. There are also a few subtleties when working inside `namespace eval` (alas; a long standing misfeature). Most of the time, just write what makes sense.

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires It basically makes no difference. You can use `tcl::unsupported::representation` to probe the difference (in 8.6), but I can tell you now that there's no fundamental difference in resulting representation. Also, `set v {}` and `set v [list]` compile to identical bytecode because there's no measurable difference anyway (and empty strings are a bit special in other ways anyway).

Answer (score 0):

As Donal wrote, `set var {}`. Internally, the same value will be assigned regardless of whether you assign `{}`, `[list]` etc. Yes, it will shimmer, and no, it won't be a problem.

Regarding `set` vs `unset`: while you can use them as you see fit, they mostly serve different patterns. In the *assign-empty-value* pattern, you want a variable ready for writing or reading, with a predefined, empty value. In the *remove-from-scope* pattern you want the name to be unused (it won't be unusable: you can still assign to / create it). Unless you're after something like the second pattern, you probably won't have much serious use for `unset`.